# clion does not index header added to target_include_derectories

Tags: cmake, header-files, clion, include-path, pkg-config

I use FindPkgConfig and then pkg_search_module to look up my dependencies. Then, I add the _INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES with target_include_directories. cmake works fine from the console and in clion, but when I try to go to definition of a header, found by pkg_search_module I get `Cannot find declaration to go`.

In the official clion manual they advise to use `include_directory` or Find_project_name.cmake files, which I cannot use, because it breaks the policy of my project.

So, does CLion understand where to look for headers found by pkg-config or how can I include the directories by hand?

Comment: Call to `pkg_search_module` just sets some variables. You need to explicitely use this variables in CMake project: `include_directories` / `target_include_directories` for add the include directories, and `target_link_libraries` for link with the library. So the problem is not with pkgconfig, but with a way you use its results.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `<module_name>_INCLUDE_DIRS` was added to `target_include_directories`, yet I see no indexing

Comment: So the question could be "CLion doesn't index a header in directory, included with `target_include_directories`", am I right? Such command may be used not only for `pkgconfig` module, but for common `find_package` too.

Comment: correct, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In CLion please try go to File menu and run "Invalidate Caches..." and restart. If all is fine the added header directory should appear under External Libraries->Header Search Paths of the Project structure Tool window.

p.s. In my case when I added external headers using CMake include_directories() the CLion started correctly recognise the symbols in the project files by didn't allow go to header definition using Ctrl+mouse click on the header file.